# What event signals that a UserControl based control is being destroyed in the WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Grid panel in my dialog populated with different controls. Some of controls are inherited from UserControl class and it is required to be perform some operations (like Tasks termination, states saving etc) before the controls will be destroyed.

What event signals that a UserControl based control is being destroyed in WPF, like `protected override void OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e)` in the WinForms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `UserControl` is not "destroyed" until it it is eventually garbage collected.

There is an [Unloaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded(v=vs.110).aspx) event that is fired when a `FrameworkElement` is removed from the element tree. Note that this event may be fired several times for the same element depending on your layout and how you display the elements.

But there is no "destroyed" event raised for a `UserControl`. All managed objects become eligible for garbage collection when there are no longer no references to them.

If your custom `UserControl` needs to be explicitly "destroyed" for some reason, you should consider implementing the [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) interface and explictly dispose the instances once you are done using them. But WPF won't call the `Dispose` method for you.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. The Unloaded event is called when my control removed from grid programmatically, but when the application is terminated it doesn't. Why? I am missing something?

Comment: No. You are not missing something. There is no event being fired for a control when the application is closed. You need to handle this scenario yourself.